# Minecraft freezing with forge despite having more than enough room

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-mods, minecraft-forge

Alright, I've been trying to run a forge 1.10.2 profile, and it works.  I'm able to get into the game with my 19 mods, but when I'm in it freezes every three seconds or so, and upon viewing the f3 key, I noticed that it keeps on hitting about 56% on the allocated memory reading on the top left then freezing and dropping down to 17 percent or so.
Oh, and before anyone suggests the whole _JAVA_OPTIONS fix, a while back I had that problem with giving it more than 512 mb, regardless of my launch variables.  I ALREADY solved that by removing the _JAVA_OPTIONS entry from environmental variables.
Here's my current launch variable line:

```
-Xmx2G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn1G
```

Now from what I've read this means that my computer allocates 2 gigabytes of RAM to minecraft.  It won't necessarily use it all if it isnt needed, but minecraft has access to it.  It currently says it's allocating something around 71% of it's given RAM at around 1300 megabytes.  Knowing this, why does my game STILL freeze up?
Possibly pertinent information:
I have 19 mods installed, but several are coremods that add no items, mobs, biomes, or other resource-heavy parts.  All are up to date.
I have nothing like a huge redstone computer, mob farm with thousands of mobs, lag-causing things like buildcraft pipe networks with ProjectE converters or any heavy machinery.  The world that I created to test is blank, freshly genned.
I'm using the default texturepack, albeit with optifine installed, and no shaders.
I have all my video settings on the minimum possible.
I DO have 64 bit java installed.
My forge is up-to-date and stable.
I have no unstable versions of mods.
EDIT: Upon testing this occurs even with the vanilla minecraft, so even if you can help me get that working again I'd be glad (also I hope that means it can stay even though the initial question is about modded AND vanilla).

Also it may not be relevant but even during the freezes my cpu usage never goes above 20 percent with the javaw.exe process associated with Minecraft.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we [no longer provide technical support for modded Minecraft](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/). If the problem persists when you run Vanilla Minecraft, please feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should try getting a resource pack called paper_cutout_3_21859379.zip it helps with fps for me when im playing 11.0 but its for 1.8 but i still use it